# Lining up Widgets in a Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, graphics, tkinter

I have been trying to create a small GUI for a definition-tester program I am making. My GUI needs to look like this:

```
Word: # label, then entry widget
Definition: # label, entry widget
Part of Speech: # label, then entry widget
Go Quit # each are buttons
```

This is what I have so far:

```
from Tkinter import *

class GetWord:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.wordL = Label(self.frame, text = 'Word: ')
        self.wordL.pack(side = 'left')
        self.wordE = Entry(self.frame)
        self.wordE.pack(side = 'right', after=self.wordL)
        self.defL = Label(self.frame, text = 'Definitions: ')
        self.defL.pack(side = 'left', after=self.wordE)
        self.defE = Entry(self.frame)
        self.defE.pack(side = 'right', after=self.defL)
        self.posL = Label(self.frame, text = 'Part of Speech: ')
        self.posL.pack(side = 'left', after=self.defE)
        self.posE = Entry(self.frame)
        self.posE.pack(side = 'right', after=self.posL)
        self.buttonE = Button(self.frame, text = 'Go', command = self.getInfo)
        self.buttonE.pack(side='bottom', after=self.posE)
        self.quitB = Button(self.frame, text = 'Quit', fg = 'red', command = self.frame.quit)
        self.quitB.pack(side='bottom', after=self.buttonE)
    def getInfo(self):
        print self.wordE.get(), self.defE.get(), self.posE.get()

root = Tk()
f = GetWord(root)
root.mainloop()
```

However, they don't line up. How can I associate them each as a 'row' (one label, one entry per 'row', and a final 'row' with the two buttons)/

Also, I'm not sure how this part works:

```
root = Tk()
f = GetWord(root)
root.mainloop()
```

`root` does not directly reference the `GetWord` class, so I don't know how it is working. If someone could explain this to me, that'd be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you must substitute `pack` with `grid`. When using `grid`, you must first name the widget (for example) `f = Label(#info)`.  Then, you set the `grid`, which is similar to pack, but allows more control. `f.grid(row =1, column = 1, sticky = W)`. To understand more about `grid`, look here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: Thanks! I added your second answer to this one as well.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND Glad I could help. There is also a third option besides pack and grid, called place, but I have not used it yet because a) I haven't needed it, and b) grid does everything how I want it, organized

Answer (score 1):

As to the second part, `root` does access the `GetWord` class. `root = Tk()` sets root as a Tkinter window. By saying `f = GetWord(root)`, you are setting the master window as `root`, meaning whatever is done to `f` is in the window with the name `root`. Then, `GetWord` does its `__init__` method. `root.mainloop()` tells the window to run and wait for any changes needed in the master window (like recognizing a button push or other events). Without this, the window will not do anything.